# How to save state across requests for an entity in ASP.NET without saving to database using EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

I'm working on a CRUD ASP.NET WebForms web application consisting of a couple of pages in which the user fills in data. My client doesn't want to store the entities in the database between pages until the user clicks Finish on the last page (for various reasons). What options are there to propagate the filled in data between the pages and which is the least bad? From my readings I've seen that ViewState and Server.Transfer can be used. Any other options, preferably using less magic strings and more type safe data binding to entity objects?

Comment: best option would be to persist this temporary data in a database. There really is no value in doing it otherwise, to the contrary. Storing it in memory can reduce the scalability of the application.

Comment: @StevenVandeWeyer - I am pretty sure there are better options

Comment: All options named in this discussion come down to client side or server side techniques. Client side techniques increase your bandwith usage. From server techniques it is clear you need to throw in some server resources. If I come to make a choice in which server resources to put to work, I mostly prefer to persist in DB. Most DB's manage server resources in a very responsible and scalable way. There could also be a specific reason to not persist in a db. Could be that they want to keep the datasource 'clean' of this data. A new db instance can be a good counterargument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ViewState` is going to significantly increase the amount of data your sending down the wire, as all `Viewstate` data is serialised into a hidden input in the form, so as you add objects your HTTP request-response is going to grow significantly.

There's no magic bullet in this really. If your data is not too complex I'd store the values in the query string. If your objects are getting complex and big and you want to maintain type safety I'd use `Session`, but remember to clean up after yourself!

a further option is to use the MVC paradigm and store the values in the form it's self using hidden inputs. This means you don't need to worry about clearing up your session if the user bugs out half way though but it also keeps your querystring clean.

think thats all your options, *querystring*, *viewstate(don't do it)*, *session* or *hidden variables*.

Ok so you have to seraialise your data, so you cannot persist the context. this is not serialiseable so the above are your options:

they each have positive and negatives,

- Viewstate (inefficent but easy to use)
- Querystring (efficent but impractical for large data sets and editable)
- Session(adds server load and needs cleaning up but allows you to persist data on the server only)
- hidden variables(hidden from user but more efficient than viewstate requires a lot of hidden inputs for each property)

Take your pick!

Comment: View state can be fine for forms, especially if the app is going to be intranet only.  Query-string on the other hand has the potential to be manipulated.  Passing anything in the query-string that is going to be used as form input data is dangerous.  The hidden fields are going to use the same amount of overhead that the session state is.  All of this doesnt really address the issue of saving the Entity object across page changes with out actually saving to the DB.

Comment: viewState serialise the object state into a binary format, therefore encoding the types, etc into the hidden input, this then needs to be serialised and then desealised each side of the request/response thus adding overhead based on hidden inputs only. I never suggested that the querystring could not be manipulated. Notice you marked me down without suggesting any better alternatives???

Comment: Also to say, "this is an intranet so lets ignore all performance measures" is pretty stupid. Just because your on a Gb ethernet does not mean that you shouldn't optimise your code as much as possible.

Comment: It is irrelevant to this question because you can not serialize the Entity context so it can not be stored in the view state.  Nor can it be stored in the Query-string or in a hidden form field.

Comment: You can't seralise the entity context full stop! So if you want to store data in a serilaised state, which you need to persist in a web form, the above are you only options. editing to explain each positive and negative

Comment: No the OP is asking to persist the entity context with out a .savechanges() call.

Comment: Then explain why you can not do that in your answer and how your alternatives can be implemented.  BTW I will not reverse my downvote so long as you include the query string as a valid place to store form data.

Comment: Where is the OP specifically asking about persisting the Entity Context? While it _may_ be possible, its highly dangerous.

Comment: at last a voice of reason!

Comment: All options in this answer are valid, but you could also add `Cache` to be complete.

Comment: Yes agreed, I won't add to my answer as someone has already posted about Memcache.

Answer (score 2):

You can store all objects used in the client application in the `Session` and then when the user clicks finish you send those objects to a service/method where you can convert them to entities and then submit them to the database.

Comment: Using session to store the Entity-Context can be dangerous.

Comment: @Chad: I never said to store the context in the session. I was only referring to the objects that contain the data - ideally a data contract or something similar that would then be converted to the entities.

Comment: @Chad: I have changed my answer to avoid any misunderstanding, I hope that is clear enough now

Comment: The op is asking specifically to have the data changes in the entity context with out a savechanges() call.  You suggested using the Session to store objects.  You can store the Context in the session but you better have some code to handle the problems that arise from it if you do.

Comment: @Chad: let me say this again: I never mentioned storing the context in the session, you're the one saying that again and again. Maybe I didn't understood well the question, but my understanding is that he wants all data to be committed to the database only when the user presses the "Finish" button: "_My client doesn't want to store the entities in the database between pages until the user clicks Finish on the last page (for various reasons)_"

Comment: @RuiJarimba - The thing is you can store the Context Object in the session.  And when you do it creates problems that can be addressed but not trivially.  My comment was simply pointing that out not saying your answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use MemCached.
there are tons of examples on the internet.
Try this :
[Implementing Distributed Caching using Memcached](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/96698/Implementing-Distributed-Caching-using-Memcached)

Comment: I don't see how cache would help in this scenario.

Comment: Reading the link I do not understand what MemCached works or how it would work to store an entity context object.

Comment: Memcache is a perfectly acceptable alternative to Session. Fast in memory data storage, as mentioned you can't store the entity context so this is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what I am doing wrong, but my ASP Web API Controller does not have Session state available?  I did this instead:
(1) went to the WebApiConfig file, where that static class is defined, as I wanted some chunk of code that would run once before my controller ever gets called. In there I added a public static List variable, myList.  (2) Then in the Register method, I finished defining that list.  (3) Now over in my controller, I have a persistent (as long as I don't restart the app) list that I can read and write too.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static List<Note> myList;
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        myList = new List<Note>();
        myList.Add(new Note { Id = "1", Subject = "Wake up", Details = "Set alarm of 7:00 am and get out of bed." });
        myList.Add(new Note { Id = "2", Subject = "Eat breakfast", Details = "Eat a healthy breakfast." });
        myList.Add(new Note { Id = "3", Subject = "Go to work", Details = "Get to work before 9:00 am." });

        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
         ... more code
```

And then in the Controller

```
public Note Save(Note newNote)
{
    WebApiConfig.myList.Add(newNote);
    return newNote;
}
```